How can I stop this default web browser dialogue popping up?
The below dialogue box has just started popping-up when I open web links from other apps. As you can see, I have Choosy set as my default browser and whatever has triggered this dialogue thinks I should use Firefox instead.
Choosy is an app appears to macOS as a browser but isn't really one. It's an app that sits behind the scenes as a default browser and opens other browsers based on configurable rules, e.g. opening Google Meet calls in Chrome

I would ordinarily think that this is triggered by Firefox (because it's not set as the default) but I have reason to believe it's coming from macOS. I have faced the same issue before on a different laptop but the suggestion was for Chrome to be my default browser. The dialogue would keep popping up no matter how I configured Chrome to NOT be my default browser. Until now I've assumed it was Chrome being overzealous in wanting to be my default browser.
I trust Firefox to not being doing the same thing so now have a theory that macOS has noticed that even though I have Choosy as my default browser I spend all my time using Firefox. Has anyone seen this dialogue before and managed to stop it popping up? I want to keep Choosy as my default browser.

The text reads:

Do you want to change your default web browser to "Firefox" or keep using "Choosy"?
Your default web browser opens when you click links in places like email messages, documents and other apps.


I think it could be that my Choosy free trial had ended. I went through the process of setting my default browser to Firefox, then back to Choosy, and have now registered it and the problem has gone away.
